# Typescript function to merge results from rest services with async/await

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await

I am trying to merge data from multiple sources with typescript, and
for some reason I cannot figure it out.

I have made two functions:

1. `async getOrdersByUserId(userId)`
2. `async getOrderDetailsByOrderId(orderId)`

These two functions calls one rest backend each which results in the following json documents:

```
{
   "orders": [
     "order1", 
     "order2"
   ],
   "name": "Sol Blomma"
}
```

and example of a json structure from `getOrderDetailsByOrderId` would be as below.

```
{
     "items": [ 
       "item1": {
         "id": "1234",
         "quantity": "50"
       },
       "item1": {
         "id": "1235",
         "quantity": "40"
       },
       "item1": {
         "id": "1236",
         "quantity": "20"
       }
      ]
}
```

How do I create a typescript function that as parameter take the userId and 
returns one structure of the json orders and all its details?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ReturnType`, to get the type of a function and `merge(union)` a return type of new function.

**Look at the example.**

```
type IFn1 = { name: string };
type IFn2 = { age: number };
const fn1 = (): IFn1 => ({ name: "deepak" });
const fn2 = (): IFn2 => ({ age: 30 });

type T10 = ReturnType<() => IFn1>; // string
type T11 = ReturnType<() => IFn2>; // void

const merge = (): T10 | T11 => {
  return {
    ...fn1(),
    ...fn2(),
  };
};

console.log(merge());

/*
// Error
const merge2 = (): T10 | T11 => {
  return {
    ...fn1(),
    ...{ age: "30" },
  };
};
console.log(merge()); // Error
*/
```